# using Castor to parse xml based on attribute values

Tags: java, xml, castor

Using [Castor](http://www.castor.org/) to parse the following xml into POJOs using a mapping file is fairly straightforward:

```
<human name="bob"/>
<dog owner="alice"/>
```

It uses the name of the element to map to the class.  But what if an attribute should be used to do the mapping?  e.g.:

```
<animal type="human" name="bob"/>
<animal type="dog" owner="alice"/>
```

This contrived example is based on XML that I have to consume (tho I didn't author it!).  Any ideas on how to approach this with Castor mapping files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. Change your Java class structure to have human and dog extend animal, and then write a mapping file for Animal.

Or just use XSLT to transform you data. Something like this might work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="animal">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="@type" /><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> </xsl:text>name="<xsl:value-of select="@name" />"
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[/>]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```